# Redirecting with Javascript appends link instead of redirecting

Tags: javascript, redirect

The script I'm writing is for an HTML page that is meant to make an ajax request, the response is an external link. Then the browser is supposed to redirect to this external URL (ex. from localhost:3000 to www.stackoverflow.com). However, the URL is appended instead (localhost:3000/"www.stackoverflow.com"). How can I redirect to a new page in pure javascript?

I've already attempted the following: window.location.href =, location.href =, window.location.replace(), window.location.assign(). All of these resulted in appending the URL instead.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
        window.location.href = http.response
    }
}
http.open("GET", "/1", true);
http.send();
```

Comment: does the http.response variable has `http://` in the beginning?

Comment: add sample base and target url

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
        window.location.href = 'http://' + http.response.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
    }
}
http.open("GET", "/1", true);
```

but if any url send by the server already has 'http://' in it, you have to treat this before assigning the url
    http.send();

The `.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "")` is for removing the double quotes your server seems to be sending also.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `response` variable looks like this:

```
'www.stackoverflow.com'
```

You should prepend `http://` (or `https://`) to it before assigning to `location.href` to ensure that the browser interprets it as an absolute (as opposed to relative) URL.

```js
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    window.location.href = 'http://' + http.response
  }
}
http.open("GET", "/1", true);
http.send();
```

If you are unsure whether your `response` contains the URL scheme, you can make your code a little more flexible with a regular expression check:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    var url = http.response
    window.location.href = (/^https?:\/\//.test(url) ? '' : 'http://') + url
  }
}
http.open("GET", "/1", true);
http.send();
```